# SQL Statement - using aliases support

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me understand how I can get my following query including subqueries and aliases working.

Ideally I don't want the `[Snapshotid]` to be as a column in the results, but be able to filter it.

```
With DistinctDates as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [SnapshotDate]
    FROM [data].[table]
)
, LastSnapshots AS
(
    SELECT 
        [SnapshotDate], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [SnapshotDate] DESC) AS SnapshotId
    FROM 
        DistinctDates
) x
SELECT
    SnapshotId,
    e.[SnapshotDate],
    e.[EmployeeNumber]
    ,e.[UserStatus]
    ,e.[AssignmentStatus]
    ,e.[EmpDateLatestStart]
    ,e.[DateOfLeaving]
    ,e.[PeriodEndDate]
    ,s.[LocationNumber]
    ,e.[DateFirstHired]
    ,e.[JobName]
FROM
    [data].[table] e,
    x.LastSnapshots
INNER JOIN 
    [data].[hierarchy] s ON e.[LocationNumber] = s.[LocationNumber] 
WHERE   
    x.SnapshotId <= 26
    AND e.[LeavingContext] IN ('Dismissal', 'End of Contract', 'Mutual Agreement', 'N/A', 'Resignation')
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Right now you dont say what is wrong or what you want. Not much we can do until you do

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanak you for your response - i am sure the structure of the above query is incorrect with the aliases - and am getting the following error  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "e.LocationNumber" could not be bound.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted the last Snapshotdate as the SnapshotId?

```
select  MAX ( e.SnapshotDate ) OVER () AS SnapshotId
        ,e.[SnapshotDate]
        ,e.[EmployeeNumber]
        ,e.[UserStatus]
        ,e.[AssignmentStatus]
        ,e.[EmpDateLatestStart]
        ,e.[DateOfLeaving]
        ,e.[PeriodEndDate]
        ,s.[LocationNumber]
        ,e.[DateFirstHired]
        ,e.[JobName]
from    [data].[table] e
        INNER JOIN [data].[hierarchy] s ON e.[LocationNumber] = s.[LocationNumber] 
WHERE   x.SnapshotId <= 26
AND     e.[LeavingContext] IN ('Dismissal','End of Contract','Mutual Agreement','N/A','Resignation')
```